# Trouble finding calling two points to one method. "Java - distancePoint"

Tags: java

I am trying to understand why I am having a difficult time calling two different points into a method in order to determine the distance between the two points.

This is the text provided on the website "Practice-It", where I am currently working through problems:

---

Add the following method to the Point class:

public double distance(Point other)

Returns the distance between the current Point object and the given other Point object. The distance between two points is equal to the square root of the sum of the squares of the differences of their x- and y-coordinates. In other words, the distance between two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2) can be expressed as the square root of (x2 - x1)2 + (y2 - y1)2. Two points with the same (x, y) coordinates should return a distance of 0.0."

---

I have tried multiple ways to get the points into the method without naming individual coordinates.  I believe that I am only getting the coordinates of the first point and am trying to understand where I am going wrong as I've had this problem before.  I realize that the "int x1 = p1.x", etc. is redundant and I could just type "p1.x" in the return, but I am wanting to see all of the moving parts individually.  Thanks for your consideration and help.

```
public double distance(Point other){
    Point p1 = new Point();
    int x1 = p1.x;
    int y1 = p1.y;
    Point p2 = new Point();
    int x2 = p2.x;
    int y2 = p2.y;

    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x * x2, 2) + Math.pow(y * y2, 2));
}
```

This is my result from one of the situations tested:

```
test #1:(5, 2) to (8, 6)
expected output:
5.0
5.0
your output:
0.0
0.0
differences:
1,2c1,2
< 5.0
< 5.0
> 0.0
> 0.0
result: fail
```

Comment: Provide the code of you point class as well and how you are calling it from your main class

Comment: The point class code is not provided on the practice website.  I am only operating under the guidelines provided.  The answer from Tim Biegelesien below was very helpful.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your comparison logic is off.  Assuming that `distance()` is a method inside the `Point` class, then you should be comparing the x,y values of the incoming `other` point against the x,y value in the class:

```
public double distance(Point other) {
    int x1 = other.x;
    int y1 = other.y;

    return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x * x1, 2) + Math.pow(this.y * y1, 2));
}
```

Note that is would be more ideal to provide getters for the `x` and `y` fields in `Point`.  Here is a more complete suggested refactor:

```
public class Point {
    private int x;
    private int y;

    public Point(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX() { return x; }
    public int getY() { return y; }

    public double distance(Point other) {
        int x1 = other.getX();
        int y1 = other.getY();

        return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.x * x1, 2) + Math.pow(this.y * y1, 2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help.  I was having trouble finding how to retain the value of x and y.  Not to mention that my return math was slightly off.  Here is the corrected return that I used:

return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x - x2, 2) + Math.pow(y - y2, 2));

Comment: You say that you appreciate the help, but it appears you have not really tried my answer.  I gave you a full implementation for `Point` which addresses your concerns.

Comment: I do see that now and have recognized my errors in the minute amount of code in comparison that I was working with.  I don't understand the fallacy of appreciation given the circumstance.  The code you provided is helpful and will allow me to implement future solutions to my problems.